# $f\in L^1(0,1)$, $xf$ absolutely continuous. Does then $(xf)(0) = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis

I have $f\in L^1(0,1)$ such that $xf$ is absolutely continuous on $[0,1]$. The latter is equivalent to $f'\in L^1_{\rm loc}(0,1)$ and $xf'\in L^1(0,1)$.

Does it follow from these assumptions that $(xf)(0) = 0$?

Comment: The only assumption you need is that $f(0)$ is a number.  By definition, $(x f) (0) = 0 \cdot f(0) = 0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael But I cannot evaluate $f$. At least not at zero. E.g., if $f(x) = x^{-1/2}$.

Comment: Oh wait. I think I can prove it: $$|(xf)(0)| = \lim_{y\to 0}\frac 1y\int_0^yx|f(x)|\,dx\le\lim_{y\to 0}\frac 1y\int_0^yy|f(x)|\,dx = \lim_{y\to 0}\int_0^y|f(x)|\,dx = 0.$$ Can anybody confirm this, please? I am not sure about the first equality.

Comment: This is correct. The first equality holds whenever $xf(x)$ is continuous at $0$. Hence absolute continuity can be replaced by continuity in the statement.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you!